# Religious organizations in India that teach Vedas or scriptures with a day job

Tags: worship, practice, india, sannyasa

For a person wanting to give up material needs, devote to God and study ancient Indian scriptures (Vedas, Upanishads etc.), are there any religious community organizations in India where he could also earn or get food two times a day while the primary focus is on Vedic studies?

Comment: This may lead to opinion based answers!

Comment: @ALL - I don't think a question such as this should be closed. I edited the question so it can be answered objectively without going too much into which organization is good, better, best etc.